# Hibernate persiste but not add FK in children

Tags: hibernate, persistence, hibernate-mapping

I try that a User can be member of several associations. To achieve this I have created:

Users

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="seqUsuario",sequenceName="SQ_USUARIO")
@GeneratedValue(generator="seqUsuario",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Integer idUsuario;

@Column(name="NOMBRE",nullable=false)
private String nombre;

@Column(name="EMAIL",nullable=false)
private String email;

@Column(name="CLAVE",nullable=false)
private String clave;


@Column(name="APELLIDOS",nullable=false)
private String apellidos;


@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="IDCALLE")
private Calle calle;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="usuario",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
private List<QSM> qsms;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="usuario",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<Miembro> miembros;
```

Association

```
    @Id
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="SQ_ASOCIACION",name="seqAsociacion")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="seqAsociacion")
private Integer idAsociacion;

@Column(name="NOMBRE",nullable=false)
private String nombre;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="asociacion",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<Miembro> miembros;
```

Member

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="SQ_MIEMBRO",name="seqMiembro")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="seqMiembro")
private Integer idMiembro;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="IDASOCIACION")
private Asociacion asociacion;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="IDUSUARIO")
private Usuario usuario;
```

SQL:Member

```
+----------------+---------+------+
| Field          | Type    | Null |
+----------------+---------+------+
| IDMIEMBRO      | int(11) | NO   |
| IDUSUARIO      | int(11) | YES  |
| IDASOCIACION   | int(11) | YES  |
+----------------+---------+------+
```

Method

```
public void nuevoUsuario(){


    //Creamos el miembro para introducirlo en la A.A.V.V

    Miembro miembro=new Miembro();
    miembro.setActivado(true);

    //Obtenemos el resourcebundle para los mensajes predefinidos

    ResourceBundle recurso=ResourceBundle.getBundle("org.pfc.mensajes.message");

    //Si la asociación vecinal no existe, se crea y el usuario pasa a presidente
    Asociacion asociacion=new Asociacion();
    if(usuario.getCalle().getBarrio().getAsociacion()==null){


        asociacion.setActivado(true);
        asociacion.setPrivado(false);
        asociacion.setNombre("A.A.V.V." + usuario.getCalle().getBarrio().getNombre());
        asociacion.setFecha(Calendar.getInstance());
        asociacion.setDescripcion(MessageFormat.format(recurso.getString("asociacion.descripcion"),usuario.getCalle().getBarrio().getNombre()));

        TipoAsociacion tipoAsociacion=asociacionBo.getTipoAsociacionByString("VECINAL");
        asociacion.setTipoAsociacion(tipoAsociacion);


        miembro.setAsociacion(asociacion);

        asociacionBo.save(asociacion);



    }
    else{

        //Si la asociación existe se añade al usuario como miembro
        usuario.getCalle().getBarrio().getAsociacion().getMiembros().add(miembro);

    }

    usuarioBo.save(usuario);
    miembro.setUsuario(usuario);

    miembroBo.save(miembro);

}
```

In this way , I save the three object. But, my idea is dont call **miembroBo.save(miembro)** And, to persist all object from User.

The problemn that I find in this code is that HibernateTemplate.save dont return ID (oracle) because it return ID relation with hibernate, If I dont change the return Id on hot-mode in debug eclipse to the real ID in database, then throw FK exception why the Id of asociation or user has nothing to do with real ID in database.

**SOLUTION FOR** *"Hibernate not return real ID from Oracle with Sequence and Triggers"*

[solution here](http://www.juliesoft.com/2007/02/hibernate-oracle-sequences-triggers-and-off-by-one%E2%80%99s/comment-page-1/#comment-5637)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For to persiste a bidirecctional relation, first there are set both side of relation and then to save the object.